# Unable to upgrade from OS X Mavericks to OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a problem upgrading the system from os x mavericks to os x yosemite. I tried to update it through the app store, but it says that it is unavailable in the UK? Can anyone explain to me what this means?

Comment: it is not yet available - be patience.

Comment: @ReneLarsen "be patience" - I agree ;)

Comment: It is now available in the Store

Answer (score 2):

It means it isn't available in your region yet. You just need to give it a bit of time.

Comment: It's not available in the U.S. Region either apparently. I get that error message in the US. That their servers are overloaded and throwing bad back bad error messages. I hope it's the latter as not having it available int he US is bad.